# Можно ли отобразить картинку только что загруженного файла в браузер (не из сервера)?

Tags: html, jquery, css, vue.js

Я хочу при добавлении картинки в браузере-её сразу же отображать, а потом уже залить на сервер. Тоесть пользователь выбрал фото для добавления в диалоговом окне и тут же отобразить содержимое 
Как такое сделать?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function () {
        var file = this.files; //Files[0] = 1st file
        if (file[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file[0], 'UTF-8');
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var result = event.target.result;
                $('.preview').attr('src', event.target.result); //Img с классом preview

            };
        }
    })
```